# Selenium will not load full Page Source, only partially through CSS styles and then cuts off

Tags: selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I have tried looking through several answers on Stack Overflow, all to no avail. When I print the page source of the webpage, I can only see the source up to a certain point within a  tag, give or take a few characters. The HTML elements beyond  are never loaded or printed out in the page source. When I attempt to load HTML elements that **should** be present (they're there when I view page source on Chrome), I get either a `TimeoutException` or a `NoSuchElementException`.

I'm parsing a dynamically loaded website after passing through a multi-factor auth portal. I've printed `driver.current_url` to ensure I am on the correct URL after MFA, have tried `sleep(100)` and tried explicitly waiting for `EC.url_contains(...)`, `EC.element_to_be_clickable(...)`, and `EC.presence_of_element_located(...)`.

Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

url = "https://brightspace.nyu.edu/d2l/home"

driver = webdriver.Chrome()     # should open a Chrome window
driver.get(url)         # navigate to brightspace

# MFA Handling Code here #

# Explicitly wait until we reach the Brightspace home page (logged in)   
element = WebDriverWait(driver,100).until(EC.url_contains('https://brightspace.nyu.edu/d2l/home'))
print(driver.page_source)
banner = driver.find_element_by_id('bannerTitle')   # throws NoSuchElementException
```

This is part of the output:

```
        <!-- ... previous styles and HTML in <head> ... -->
        <style is="custom-style">html {
                        --d2l-color-woolonardo: var(--d2l-color-sylvite);
                        .
                        .   lots of colors
                        .
                        --d2l-color-olivine-light-1: var(--d2l-color-olivine-plus-1);
                        --d2l
                        <!-- ^^ the page source cuts off here, in <head> -->
```

with the last line giving the following error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="bannerTitle"]"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In stead of `banner = driver.find_element_by_id` I would suggest using `WebDriverWait`, `By` and `EC`. I would also put `print(driver.page_source)` after the banner is found. We can try scrolling down the page as well. Below I commented out some of your lines and added my suggested updates.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

url = "https://brightspace.nyu.edu/d2l/home"

driver = webdriver.Chrome()     # should open a Chrome window
driver.get(url)         # navigate to brightspace

# MFA Handling Code here #

# Explicitly wait until we reach the Brightspace home page (logged in)   
element = WebDriverWait(driver,100).until(EC.url_contains('https://brightspace.nyu.edu/d2l/home'))
# print(driver.page_source)
# banner = driver.find_element_by_id('bannerTitle')   # throws NoSuchElementException
##################################
######## NEW SUGGESTIONS #########
##################################
banner = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 100).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(
        (By.ID, "bannerTitle")))
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
print(driver.page_source)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I modified your code a bit to using the By module with classname instead: ```EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "d2l-image-banner-overlay"))```, and it worked!

Comment: @LiamRM : You should mark this answer as an acceptable answer if it worked for you.